# Manipulating Implicit Differentiation Problem

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on this problem involving implicit differentiation.

The instructions ask me to find $y'$, the problem is:

$(x-2y)^3 = 2y^2 - 3$

So far I've been able to get this far:

$3(x-2y)^2 (1-2y') = 4y(y')$

I've been trying to manipulate it for a while but I can't figure out how to finish the problem properly.

Comment: You just need to solve for $y'$, so (1) Multiply everything out (2) Bring all the terms involving $y'$ to the LHS of the equals sign.  (3) Bring all the terms that don't involve $y'$ to the RHS of the equals sign.  (4) Divide by the coefficient of $y'$ on both sides to solve for $y'$.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Burr gave a way to do it.

Another way could be to consider the implicit function$$f=(x-2y)^3 -2y^2 +3 =0$$ Compute its derivative with respect to $x$ and $y$ $$f'_x=3 (x-2 y)^2$$ $$f'_y=-6 (x-2 y)^2-4 y$$ Now, use the implicit function theorem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{f'_x}{f'_y}=-\frac{3 (x-2 y)^2}{-6 (x-2 y)^2-4 y}=\frac 3 2\times\frac{ (x-2 y)^2}{3 (x-2 y)^2+2 y}$$